# Can I load certain data from the database when adding services to the WebApplicationBuilder in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am adding Google authentication to my website and loading the `ClientId` and `ClientSecret` from the appsettings.json file but I want to store them in the database and load them from there in the Program.cs file before building my app and running it. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure... Download the file content from a database, write to disk, then use Google SDK functions. No different than first downloading files from Google websites

Comment: _"Is that possible?"_ - yes, there are multiple approaches to this. From just reading the database in the `Program` file to creating [custom settings provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#custom-configuration-provider). But in general I would recommend against storing such data in database - usually it's better to manage such via designated key stores or via environment variables.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.